# PDF created in TCPDF can not be opened in AdobeReader

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have PHP code that creates PHP files on the fly using TCPDF.

```
public function createRegulationPDF(){
    require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');
    $pageDimension = array('500,300'); //width,height
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);        
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('CopyrightPolska.com.pl');
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);    
    $pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);
    $width = $pdf->pixelsToUnits(768); 
    $height = $pdf->pixelsToUnits(1024);
    $resolution= array($width, $height);
    $pdf->AddPage('P', $resolution);
    $html = $this->view->render('index/summaryForPDF.phtml');
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');       
    $pdf->Output('exampleDownloaded.pdf', 'D');
    return $pdf;
}
```

Next, this PDF is downloaded as exampleDownloaded.pdf and (at the same time) is attached to the email:

```
$filename = "exampleAttached.pdf";
        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
        $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
```

I try to open the files in Adobe ReaderŁ
1. **exampleDownloaded - can not be opened in Adobe** 
[image: pdferror.png]
2. exampleAttached - is opened without any problems

Does someone know why PDF dowloaded can not be open?

Comment: Did you open the file in a regular text editor to ensure it doesn't have bogus stuff inside, such as PHP error messages or your web site's HTML structure?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. I didn't know that I can open PDF in text editor. And, you are right, there is some PHP/HTML code. When I remove it I can open this file in AdobeReader. Hot to avoid this PHP code in PDF file?

Comment: Well, PHP code does not get scattered in your output by default. How does it get there in the first place?

Comment: First, PHP is created with method in description, then $pdf->Output('exampleDownloaded.pdf', 'D'); allow to download created PDF, and next the function returns this pdf. And returned PDF is attached to email (here it is ok).

Comment: But, do you really get raw unparsed PHP code after executing a PHP script? That means that such code is not executed. Are you using short PHP tags in a server that's configured to only accept long tags?

Comment: I got in PDF file HTML tags. Not PHP. It seems that PHP code is executed, because I see that in PDF source is text coming from PHP include. PHP is working ok, but PDF contains HTML and JavaScript code.